# If third law of motion is acceptable in unbalanced force

Tags: forces

If third law of motion is acceptable in unbalanced force then why the object moves as by third law the force which we are applying like 10N then it should come back to us but in this case the object is moving

Comment: Can you explain yourself further.  In particular, what do you believe an "unbalanced force" is?  Newton's Third Law states that every force is balanced by an equal and opposite reaction.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you're missing out the fact that the _action_ and _reaction_ forces act on separate bodies. **Not** the same body.

Answer (score 3):

The third law says that action and reaction are equal and opposite, so if I push the object with a force of $10$N then the object pushes me with a force of $-10$N. That means the object accelerates due to the force I apply to it and I decelerate due to the opposite force the object applies on me.

This is a point that frequently causes confusion. The third law doesn't say the action and reaction cancel out to give no force. In a two body interaction the action acts on one of the bodies and the reaction acts on the other body. So both bodies experience a non-zero force and both bodies accelerate (or decelerate).

Answer (score 0):

If an object has only one 10 N force acting on it and that force is provided by you then that object has an unbalanced force of 10 N acting on it.

At the same time, because you are applying a 10 N force on the **object**, Newton's third law tells you that the object is applying a 10 N force in the opposite direction on **you**.

So the Newton third law pair of forces act on two different bodies:
on the object - a force of 10 N
and
on you - a force of 10 N.

Because these two 10 N forces act on different bodies they do not cancel each other out.